# Change Kubernetes secrets file format in mounted volume

Tags: kubernetes, aws-secrets-manager, kubernetes-secrets

I am able to get a secrets file pulled from AWS Secrets Manager and mounted in the container. The format of the secrets file is as follows:

```
{"testkey":"datepie"}
```

How do I reformat the file to be like this:

```
testkey=datepie
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-app
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: test-service-account
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: 111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test.example:test-service-1.0.0-main
        volumeMounts:
          - name: test-secrets
            mountPath: /mnt/
            readOnly: true
. . .
      volumes:
      - name: test-secrets
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: test-secrets
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Turing85 questions about ConfigMap and Secrets are on-topic, its about configuring the environment variables for the app the developer develops.

Comment: Added my manifest file to the question - it's one step downstream beyond devops...

Comment: @NovaS. There is no way to transform the content in Secrets - Kubernetes only mounts what is in the Secret.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, that's what I thought. I'll see if the AWS secrets format can be changed within AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is what you get. The volume mount form will only ever be the value with the key as a filename.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Use the desired format in the AWS Secrets Manager itself, so in the "Secret value" part, select "Plaintext" and put `testkey=datepie` in the box. The "Secret key/value" tab will no longer be usable, which is not an issue.

[image]